# error: Unknown character set: 'utf8_unicode_ci'

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

Upon creating a database from the mysql command line with character sets, I get the following error: `Unknown character set: utf8_unicode_ci`. But, when I run the same SQL in phpmyadmin, it works fine with no errors and I cant figure out why?

The SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE sx CHARACTER SET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

mysql command line:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword  -h localhost --default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: `mysql> CREATE DATABASE sx CHARACTER SET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (5.59 sec)` What mysql version do you use?

Comment: @zerkms:version is:5.5.29

Answer (score 10):

Since you're getting the error `Unknown character set: 'utf8_unicode_ci'`, you must be specifying `utf8_unicode_ci` (which is a *collation*) as the *character set*.  Check your command and try again.

Comment: no, the sql syntax is correct, it works when i run the command solely now but when i run several sql commands  in a script i get this error

Comment: @HenrikSandin: If you get this error when you "*run several sql commands in a script*", how can you be certain that it's this command that has caused the error?

Comment: ah, after some debugging , i find out that it wasn't the create database command that  was the culprit, i got fooled by ysql's error statement: near "create database sx",

Answer (score 9):

Change your DB_CHARSET **utf8_general_ci** to **utf8**